# Views relationship to second database

Tags: 8, database, views

Is there any possibility to add a relationship in views from a second database to the default one. I.e. I am using a second database which contains one table with a userid. In my hook_views_data I would like to add a relationship from this field to users_field_data uid. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you define join table on hook_view_data?

Comment: yes i did and included 'table' => 'default' . '.users_field_data' in the join

Comment: And did you add field relationship on views settings?

Comment: Go to **admin/structure/views/settings** and check to **Show the SQL query**. This setting will show sql query. It's better for debug. And Can you provide your code in function hook_view_data() and your views?

Answer (score 0):

I was logged out. Yes I tried to add field relationship on views settings, but my joined table was not shown. Consider that I want to join from a view showing my table to the users_field_data table, not vice versa.

my view is simply showing the the fields from my custom table. This works. But I can't add a relationship to the second db.
The SQL query is

```
SELECT my_tracking.id AS id, my_tracking.uid AS my_tracking_uid, my_tracking.event_id AS my_tracking_event_id
FROM {my_tracking} my_tracking
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

my hook_views_data looks like

```
$data['my_tracking']['table']['name'] = 'event_tracking' . '.my_tracking';

$data['my_tracking']['table']['group'] = t('Event Tracker');

$data['my_tracking']['table']['base'] = array(
  'field' => 'id',
  'title' => t('Event Tracker'),
  'help'  => t('Contains data about tracking events.'),
  'database' => 'event_tracking',
);

$data['my_tracking']['table']['join'] = array(
  'users_field_data' => array(
    'table' => 'default' . '.users_field_data',
    'left_field' => 'uid',
    'field'      => 'uid',
  ),
);

$data['my_tracking']['table']['provider'] = 'my_tracking';


$data['my_tracking']['id'] = array(
  'title' => t('Record ID'),
  'field' => array(
    'id' => 'numeric',
  ),
  'sort' => array(
    'id' => 'standard',
  ),
  'filter' => array(
    'title' => t('Record ID'),
    'id' => 'numeric',
  ),
  'argument' => array(
    'id' => 'numberic',
  ),
);

$data['my_tracking']['uid'] = array(
  'title' => t('UID'),
  'help'  => t("The user's UID."),
  'field' => array(
    'id' => 'numeric',
  ),
  'sort' => array(
    'id' => 'standard',
  ),
  'filter' => array(
    'title' => t('UID'),
    'id' => 'numeric',
  ),
  /*  'relationship' => array(
    'title'              => t('User who is tracked'),
    'help'               => t('The user associated with the record.'),
    'id'                 => 'standard',
    'base'               => 'users_field_data',
    'base field'         => 'uid',
    'field'              => 'uid',
    'label'              => t('The who is tracked'),
  ),*/
  'argument' => array(
    'id' => 'numeric',
  ),
);

$data['my_tracking']['event_id'] = array(
  'title' => t('Event ID'),
  'field' => array(
    'id' => 'numeric',
  ),
  'sort' => array(
    'id' => 'standard',
  ),
  'filter' => array(
    'title' => t('Event ID'),
    'id' => 'numeric',
  ),
  'argument' => array(
    'id' => 'numberic',
  ),
);
```

No relationship can be added in views. Previously when I used a single database I was able to add the relationship by using the relatationship handler that is commented out above now. I don't know how to adapt it to 2 databases.

Comment: Do you have one or two table? In your code, I see only one table **my_tracking**.

Comment: only one table. I can show this table in views correctly. Now I want to join to user_field_data table

Comment: You can try comment array **$data['my_tracking']['table']['join']**. And uncomment relationship on **$data['my_tracking']['uid']**. Add relation to User The user associated with the record. Remember clear cache after edit hook_view_data

Comment: Already tried, doesn't work as the table users_field_data is in the default (main) database and can't be found by views. I also tried to prefix it 'base' => 'my_main_db.users_field_data' but this doesn't work as views builds aliases and a dot (.) is not accepted. If I output the query:  ... LEFT JOIN my_main_db.users_field_data my_main_db.users_field_data_my_tracking ON...

Comment: Don't add prefix, just define exactly table name. Try remove some line **$data['my_tracking']['table']['name'] = 'event_tracking' . '.my_tracking';**  **'database' => 'event_tracking',**. Or just copy code in [dblog.views.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21dblog%21dblog.views.inc/8.2.x) and replace **watchdog** with your table name. It's good example.

Comment: In this case view tries to join to the same database. Error message: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'event_tracking.users_field_data' doesn't exist.

Comment: Looks like you posted as another user.  Can you use the contact form at the bottom and request an account merge and then edit this "answer" into the original question?  Thanks.